# cannot navigate to same route with different params

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Is it possible in `react-native` to navigate through the same route with different params? When I tried it, it keeps getting me an error saying that the params are undefined. Here is my code:

```
function Home({ route, navigation }){
const { newText } = route.params;
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:30, paddingVertical:150, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Current Balance: {JSON.stringify(newText)} PHP</Text>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("AddBalance")}>
    <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Add Balance</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("ViewCode")}>
    <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>View Code To Pay</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Login")}>
    <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Logout</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
 );
}

function AddBalance({ navigation }){
const[balance, newBalance] = useState(0)
const[amount, setAmount] = useState()

function addTogether(){
const Total = balance + amount;
newBalance(Total);
MyFunction();
}
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{fontSize:30, paddingVertical:20, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Add Balance</Text>
    <TextInput style={styles.inputBox} placeholder="Enter Amount" keyboardType={'numeric'} 
    onChangeText={(text) => setAmount(Number.parseInt(text))}></TextInput>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress ={addTogether}>
      <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Continue</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home", {newText: 
       balance})}>
      <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Back</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity> 
    </View>
);
}

function ViewCode({ navigation }){
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text style={{fontSize:30, fontWeight:'bold'}}>Your Code is:</Text>
  <Text style={{fontSize:20, textAlign:'center'}}>R3fGH7X95iW</Text>
  <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}>
    <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Back</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  </View>
);
}
```

So the error goes when I navigate to `ViewCode` to pay and click the back button. How can I solve this? I also created a duplicate screen for a home to manage to go back to the home screen but when I tried to navigate to the duplicate home screen, the current balance became 0 again. What I want to do is whenever the user go back to home screen the current balance will base upon the balance the users added.

Comment: I think this should be possible, but a better approach would be to setup an redux store.

Comment: can you post the complete error messages?

Comment: Here you can find an working sample -> https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/passing-parameters-to-routes-%7C-react-navigation

Comment: Render Error
undefined is not an object(evaluating 'route.params.newText')

Comment: I can actually see the changes on the current balance that was located on the home whenever I navigate to Add Balance button and click the back button inside add balance .however, when I go to view code to pay buttons and click the back button inside it will either throw an error or change the current balance and set to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `Home`, you assume `route.params` always there (codes below)

```js
const { newText } = route.params;
```

but, when you press the back button in `ViewCode`, it will call `navigate.navigation("Home");` without any params. (codes below)

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.btnLogin1} onPress={()=>navigation.navigate("Home")}>
    <Text style={styles.btnLogin}>Back</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

This will lead to the error that you got.

The solution is to make the param optional. You can replace this code:

```js
const { newText } = route.params;
```

to

```
const { newText } = route.params || {newText: ""};
```

You can replace `""` with any other text as the default `newText`.

For saving the value globally, I recommend using `Context` from `React`. You can read more about it [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Here is the example of a `Provider` component you can use:

```js
const ExampleContext = React.createContext({
  setBalance: null,
  balance: "",
});

const ExampleProvider = (props) => {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");

  return (
    <ExampleContext.Provider
      value={{
        balance: balance,
        setBalance: setBalance,
      }}
    >
      {props.children}
    </ExampleContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and wrap your navigator with `ExampleProvider`

then call `setBalance` from the new context like this:

```
function AddBalance({ navigation }){
const balanceContext = React.useContext(ExampleContext);
const[amount, setAmount] = useState()

function addTogether(){
const Total = balance + amount;
balanceContext.setBalance(Total);
MyFunction();
}
```

and get balance from context instead from the `route.params`

```js
function Home({ route, navigation }){
const balanceContext = React.useContext(ExampleContext);
const newText = balanceContext.balance;
```

Comment: is there a way I can get the value I passed into the route.params and store it to other newText? because what I want is to navigate to home whenever the user click the back button on view code to pay and the current balance is still based on the amount the users added. Because what's happening in the code is when I clicked the back button the current balance changed to " " instead of the balance of the users they have added.

Comment: I can actually see the changes on the current balance that was located on the home whenever I navigate to Add Balance button and click the back button inside add balance .however, when I go to view code to pay buttons and click the back button inside it will either throw an error or change the current balance and set to 0.

Comment: you can use React.Context for that. I'll update my answer with that later.

Comment: thanks, mann really appreciate it!!

Comment: @anonymous1234 I updated the answer